# Calculating $\int\frac{1}{(x^2+2x+3)\sqrt{x}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

My attempt:

Factor the denominator: The denominator can be factored as $(x + 1)(x + 3)$.

Substitution: Let's substitute $u = x + 1$. Notice that $du = dx$.

Rewrite the integral: Substitute $x$ and $dx$ in terms of $u:
\displaystyle\int\dfrac{1}{(x+1)(x+3)\sqrt{x}}~dx$  becomes  $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{1}{u(u+2)(\sqrt{u-1})}~du$.

I could go further. Please help me.

Comment: Is that supposed to be $$\int \frac{dx}{(x^2+2x+3)\sqrt x}?$$

Comment: I guess $(x+1)(x+3)$ is not equal to your denominator quadratic.

Comment: $(x+1)(x+3)\neq x^2+2x+3.$

Comment: Moreover can you guess the substitution so that the $\sqrt{x}$ in the denominator can be removed via making change of variable?

Answer (score 1):

Your factorization of the quadratic in the denominator is incorrect: In fact, the quadratic is irreducible over $\Bbb R$, since its discriminant is negative: $2^2 - 4 \cdot 1 \cdot 3 = -8$.

**Hint** Changing variables via $u = \sqrt x$ rationalizes the integral, so that it can be handled in the usual way:
$$\int \frac{du}{u^4 + 2 u^2 + 3} .$$
Now see this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186356/evaluation-of-int-frac1x4-5x216dx), which is identical except for the constants.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_\pm =\sqrt{2(\sqrt3\pm 1)}$
\begin{align}
&\int\frac{1}{(x^2+2x+3)\sqrt{x}}\,dx
=\int\frac{\frac1{\sqrt{x^3}}}{x+\frac3x+2}\ dx\\
 =&\ \frac1{\sqrt3}\int\frac{(\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}+\frac{\sqrt3}{2\sqrt{x^3}})-( \frac1{2\sqrt{x}}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2\sqrt{x^3}})}{x+\frac3x+2}\ dx\\
 =&\ \frac1{\sqrt3}\int\frac{d(\sqrt{x}-\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt{x}})}{a_+^2+(\sqrt{x}-\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt{x}}) ^2} + \frac{d(\sqrt{x}+\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt{x}})}{a_-^2-(\sqrt{x}+\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt{x}}) ^2} \\
=& \ \frac1{\sqrt3 a_+}\tan^{-1}\frac{{x}-{\sqrt3}}{a_+\sqrt x}
+ \frac1{\sqrt3 a_-}\coth^{-1}\frac{{x}+{\sqrt3}}{a_-\sqrt x}
\end{align}